# iframe Javascript can write parent properties but not read them

Tags: javascript, html, security, redirect, iframe

I have an iframe containing a site on a different domain.  In the iframe's Javascript, I can change the location of the lop page:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

However, if I try to access this location:

```
window.top.location == "http://www.example.com";
```

I get:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'valueOf'
```

Can you read properties of the enclosing page or are they write-only?  If they are write-only, why?

Comment: You seem to be missing the href property on your read call. You are trying to compare the location object

Comment: @tik27 Trying to access `window.top.location.href` yields `Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'`